# Which assembler dialect is the following syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

```
and dword ptr [edi], not (1 shl 2)
```

Would you mind pointing to literature that describes this dialect and/or  provide equal syntax in other dialects? An explanation of the line would be helpful as well for my own edification.

FWIW, I am trying to port instructions in this dialect to coreboot which I believe uses, I guess, a GNU dialect. When I attempt to assemble with this instruction unchanged I get the following error from i386-elf-gcc:

```
./src/drivers/intel/fsp/cache_as_ram.inc: Assembler messages:
./src/drivers/intel/fsp/cache_as_ram.inc:74: Error: junk `PTR [edi]' after expression
./src/drivers/intel/fsp/cache_as_ram.inc:74: Error: too many memory references for `and'
```

Comment: Is that the only line you got? If not and you hand-picked this out of longer code (where the rest would be more "usual"), can you show some initialization lines such as `.public code` as well?

Comment: `not (1 shl 2)` is just a constant. No idea which assembler uses this syntax, but you can easily calculate and use the value yourself in any other assembler.

Comment: This is Microsoft Assembler (MASM) but this would also work with later versions of TASM that support 32-bit code. JWAsm would also support this syntax because it is mostly MASM compatible. The giveaway that this is likely MASM is that it used _PTR_ in _DWORD PTR_. Many non-MASM compatible assemblers would have been _DWORD [EDI]_

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Some additional background, I am trying to port some MASM assembly to run in coreboot. As far as I know it uses romcc as well as gcc in the build process. Does anyone know how this instruction would be encoded under gnu assembler? Using this syntax reports assembler errors with "junk" at this line.

Comment: GNU assembler would probably look something like  `andl $~(1<<2), (%edi)` . Constants in GNU Assembler have to start with `$`. The `~`(tilde) is the NOT operator. `<<` operator is same as SHL. Registers need to be prepended with a `%` in normal AT&T syntax. `ANDL` is the and instruction dealing with LONG (4-byte) byte values (LONG=DWORD). The parentheses around `(%edi)` are same as the `PTR` directive in MASM.Source operands are on the left and destination is on the right in AT&T syntax (backwards compared to MASM). Would be read as `AND` the LONG(DWORD) value pointed by _EDI_ with value `-5`

Comment: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/faq/converting/asm.html is a good starting point regarding typical MASM/TASM to GAS (GNU assembler).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft Macro Assembler (ml.exe) [also known as MASM or MASM32] understands this construct.

Its equal to:

```
and dword ptr [edi], 0fffffffbh
```

How?

1. `1 shl 2` is equal to 4 (you move 1 two positions to the left: `100` in base 2 or `4` in base 10)
2. Thus we have `not 4` (you invert all bits in 100 in base 2)
3. which gives `11111111111111111111111111111011` in base 2 (we are on 32-bit)
4. this is equal to `0fffffffbh` (0x0fffffffb ; `4294967291` in decimal)

Comment: As far as 32-bit values go unsigned 4294967291 is signed -5 (decimal).

Comment: Intel's own assembler uses syntax similar to Microsoft's assembler, but I don't think it includes the dot directives (.if .else .endif, .... ).